# Need json deserializer for 3rd-party case class

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

I'm implementing a SecureSocial service for my Scala Play! application.  I'm using the ReactiveMongoPlugin to access the MongoDB store.  Here is the code...

```
lazy val users:  JSONCollection = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db.collection[JSONCollection]("users")

def find(providerId: String, userId: String): Future[Option[BasicProfile]] = {
  users
    .find(Json.arr(Json.obj("providerId" -> providerId), Json.obj("userId" -> userId)))
    .cursor[BasicProfile]
    .headOption
}
```

BasicProfile is a SecureSocial case class that does not implement the json serializer/deserializer.  So predictably I'm getting...

```
No Json deserializer found for type securesocial.core.BasicProfile
```

I know how to implement reads/writes for my own case classes but I'm too new to Scala to know how to do this for library case classes like BasicProfile.  How can I add json read/write to BasicProfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `Reads` and `Writes` to library case classes is really similar to adding them to your own classes. You will need to create a `Read` and a `Write` for each library case class. For example, let's say we had these case classes:

```
case class Example(a: String, b: ExampleB)
case class ExampleB(c: Int)
```

They should be parsed using these:

```
implicit val exampleWrites: Writes[Example] = (
  (JsPath \ "a").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "b").write[ExampleB]
)

implicit val exampleBWrites: Writes[ExampleB] = (
  (JsPath \ "c").write[Int]
)

implicit val exampleReads: Reads[Example] = (
  (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "b").read[ExampleB]
)

implicit val exampleBReads: Reads[ExampleB] = (
  (JsPath \ "c").read[Int]
)
```

Since these `Reads` and `Writes` are implicit, importing them should automatically make them work where you need them.

See the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) for more information.

Comment: I had tried that earlier but got the compile error `Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext`.  Upon reading the error again I see all I needed to do was add `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`.  Now it works.  Thanks!